# Why can't I connect to the internet?

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking, thinkpad

When I try to connect to my network with wireless, the network I want to connect to is grayed out. Wired works fine. The network is WPA2, and I am using Ubuntu 12.04 on an IBM Thinkpad T30 with an Intel Pentium 4M processor. Wireless works fine with Windows 7 (It's a Dual-Boot). I have only 512 MB RAM. Any suggestions can and will help!

Answer (score 0):

Researching on forums, it looks like your card is not supported properly. Try(in a terminal) `sudo apt-get install linux-wlan-ng-firmware linux-wlan-ng hostap-utils`

If you don't know what to do with the commands you above, you may press CTRL+ALT+T and then type the command(Or paste with `right-click`>`PASTE` as Terminal uses `Ctrl+V` for something else.)

Source: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1848327

Comment: Sorry, but it does not work. My network is still grayed out. Let me explain it to you: I can go to the network menu, but my Home Router is not clickable.

Comment: @HaiHai Have you rebooted yet?

Answer (score 0):

The stock Wireless card in the T30 does not support WPA in any manner and I had difficulty getting it to work even with WEP. You will need to find another Mini-PCI wireless adapter that supports WPA2. Newegg has one, but unfortunately it is not a simple hardware fix. You also have to run an unofficial BIOS patch to prevent an 1802 post code on boot (unauthorized network device). To find this fix you simply need to Google "Thinkpad 1802 error fix." You should find an ISO image to burn to a CD. Burn this disc, reboot to this disc and run the patch. Once completed, you can install ANY wireless Mini-PCI card that you wish, not just one that IBM sold with the machine.

Comment: If he is able to connect using Windows 7, looks like the *linux kernel driver* for T30, rather than the card itself, is the one  lacking WPA/WEP support.